# Determining whether the distribution of prime numbers is random or whether is there a pattern to it

Tags: number-theory

Regarding the article below, it was mentioned that prime numbers can only end with digits 1,3,7 or 9 (except for 2 and 5) but that the frequency of that these digits occur are not random, as can be seen from the fact that it is unlikely that the same digit will occur twice for consecutive prime numbers. However the article also mentions that as the prime number tends to infinity, then the distribution of prime numbers also tends to become random. If it is true then how do we prove this fact and can we conclude that the distribution of primes is random or whether it is not random and there is in fact a pattern to it?

http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/maths-experts-stunned-as-they-crack-a-pattern-for-prime-numbers-a6933156.html

Comment: By definition the prime number distribution can not be "random".  But I'll cede the point for lack/difficulty of a better term.  The pattern becomes more "random" for sequences of larger primes but that still means the earlier distribution is has the property and are not "random".  No one at this time knows how to prove this result or why it is true.

Comment: @fleablood that bothers me too, it is really more accurate to talk about statistics of the primes in this way.  The digits mentioned are statistically less likely to repeat earlier on.

Comment: What i think is that if we consider a small subset of primes then we may find that those primes does not appear randomly but say if we consider infinitely many primes then we can in fact see that the primes does occur randomly that means that each of the digits 2,3,7 ,9 has a 0.25 percent chance of occuring.?

Comment: See also "Chebychev bias" (googleable).

Comment: It gets *closer* to .25.  But even if there comes a point where it becomes .25 and from that point on the primes are "random", that doesn't change the fact that this was significant for primes less than that point.

Comment: "if we consider a small subset of primes"  By no stretch of the imagination can 400 billion be considered a "small subset" and with a variation of 6.8 off the projected 25% *and* with a steady and observable increase from 18.2 to almost 25% than something is clearly going on.  And don't forget that as primes get larger they become less common.  There is clearly so "non 'random' conspiracy" going on, the strength of which is related to the density (how common) primes are.    Even if it dwindles to zero, it is still there.

Comment: @yswong The ending digit $2$ will not appear with frequency $0.25$, but the ending digit $1$ :)

Comment: Despite of the Chebychev bias, the proportion of the primes of the form $km+n$ with $0<n<m$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$ tends to $\frac{1}{\phi(m)}$. This does not tell anything about the absolute frequencies, but means that the prime sequence has at least a basic property of a random sequence. Of course, the primes are not actually random because they are determined. But since no pattern is actually known for the "prime-universe", the term "random" has its point.

Comment: For example, the race between the primes of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ seems to favour the primes of the form $4k+3$, but it is known that the lead changes infinite many often.

Answer (score 0):

Prime numbers follow many patterns like the pattern that the last digit must be 1,3,7,9 with two small exceptions. P must be odd, and with one small exception p, p+2, p+4 cannot all three be primes. On the other hand, they can be approximated by random numbers with some extra rules.

But then thing like the twin prime theory or goldbach’s conjecture are hard to prove because primes are not random enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as this article is concerned: The last digit of the next prime will only be the same if two primes are 10, 20, 30 etc. apart and not 2-8, 12-18 etc. Since consecutive primes in the range up to 400 billion are close together, the smaller distances (2-8 vs 10, 12-18 vs 20 etc. ) will happen more often. In that range about one in 14 odd numbers are prime, so this will happen.

They haven’t detected any non-randomness, but were just careless making wrong assumptions what random behaviour would look like.